# can't install tensorflow on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN

Tags: installation, tensorflow, runtime-error, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed the Tensorflow many times but still met errors. The system always tells me that:

> failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN" and "kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host:/proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist

[image: Here is the a picture of the terminal]

Comment: Did you install the Nvidia drivers before installing CUDA?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I install the default nvidia drivers in the CUDA.

Comment: Try installing the latest Nvidia drivers first, and then telling the CUDA installer not to install the bundled ones.

Comment: Write those steps as a part of your question, and specify what is the error you get.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't know if  I do some steps wrong so I write those steps as part of my question. The error I got is the computer has blackscreen and can't go back to the normal graphical interfaces.